# FFmpeg - Libavcodec - unable to compile, errors on files not found, but files are there

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, cmake, clang, cmakelists-options

This is less about C++, and more about specific compiling avcodec and avformat as those are used inside **FFmpeg**. I'm trying to compile for the first time ffmpeg project code. All the linking has been resolved, and the program errors our.

I'm writing my first program - attempt at avformat libraries inside my C++ code. Linker errors on this line:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/sasha/CLionProjects/ffmpeg-01 --target all -- -j 12
Scanning dependencies of target docs
[  5%] Generating HTML documentation
[ 20%] Building C object lib/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/input.c.o
[ 20%] Building C object lib/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/init.c.o
[ 20%] Building C object lib/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/context.c.o
[ 30%] Building C object lib/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/vulkan.c.o
[ 30%] Building C object lib/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/monitor.c.o
[ 35%] Building C object lib/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/cocoa_init.m.o
[ 45%] Building C object lib/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/cocoa_joystick.m.o
[ 45%] Building C object lib/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/window.c.o
[ 50%] Building C object lib/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/cocoa_monitor.m.o
[ 60%] Building C object lib/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/cocoa_window.m.o
[ 60%] Building C object lib/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/cocoa_time.c.o
[ 60%] Built target docs
[ 65%] Building C object lib/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/posix_thread.c.o
[ 70%] Building C object lib/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/nsgl_context.m.o
[ 75%] Building C object lib/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/egl_context.c.o
[ 80%] Building C object lib/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/osmesa_context.c.o
[ 85%] Linking C static library libglfw3.a
[ 85%] Built target glfw
[ 95%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ffmpeg_01.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ffmpeg_01.dir/src/load_frame.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable ffmpeg_01
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'VideoToolbox'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreFoundation'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreMedia'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreVideo'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreServices'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'OpenGL'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreImage'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'AppKit'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Foundation'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreAudio'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'AVFoundation'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreGraphics'
make[2]: *** [ffmpeg_01] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ffmpeg_01.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is the content of my **libavcodec.pc* file, and it has an entry of *conflicts:* which lists all of the items that clang cannot find, I don't know if those are linked somehow. I found a source pointing that similar error appears if I had other forks of ffmpeg, but I do not.

```
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=/usr/local/lib
includedir=/usr/local/include

Name: libavcodec
Description: FFmpeg codec library
Version: 58.108.100
Requires: libswresample >= 3.8.100, libavutil >= 56.60.100
Requires.private: 
Conflicts:
Libs: -L${libdir}  -lavcodec -liconv -lm -llzma -lz -framework AudioToolbox -L/usr/local/Cellar/x264/r3011/lib -lx264 -pthread -framework VideoToolbox -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreServices
Libs.private: 
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

I don't have experience in cmakefile, I can paste it here if needed.
Any help is greatly appreciated, because I'm stuck for the past several days.

I have two CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(ffmpeg_01)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_subdirectory(lib/glfw)
add_subdirectory(lib/FFmpeg)

add_definitions(-DGL_SILENCE_DEPRECIATION)

if(APPLE)
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS
            "-framework OpenGL"
            )
elseif(LINUX)
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS
            "-lGL -lGLU -lX11")
endif()

add_executable(ffmpeg_01 src/main.cpp src/load_frame.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ffmpeg_01 FFmpeg glfw ${EXTRA_LIBS})
```

and the interface for FFmpeg under FFmpeg sub directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(FFMPEG)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

pkg_check_modules(AVCODEC    REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavcodec)
pkg_check_modules(AVFORMAT   REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavformat)
pkg_check_modules(AVFILTER   REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavfilter)
pkg_check_modules(AVDEVICE   REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavdevice)
pkg_check_modules(AVUTIL     REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavutil)
pkg_check_modules(SWRESAMPLE REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libswresample)
pkg_check_modules(SWSCALE    REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libswscale)

add_library(FFmpeg INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL)

target_link_libraries(FFmpeg INTERFACE PkgConfig::AVCODEC)
target_link_libraries(FFmpeg INTERFACE PkgConfig::AVFORMAT)
target_link_libraries(FFmpeg INTERFACE PkgConfig::AVFILTER)
target_link_libraries(FFmpeg INTERFACE PkgConfig::AVDEVICE)
target_link_libraries(FFmpeg INTERFACE PkgConfig::AVUTIL)
target_link_libraries(FFmpeg INTERFACE PkgConfig::SWRESAMPLE)
target_link_libraries(FFmpeg INTERFACE PkgConfig::SWSCALE)
```

I also tried adding the following block below target_link_libraries, but no difference on compilation outcome:

```
target_link_options(FFmpeg INTERFACE
        ${AVCODEC_LDFLAGS_OTHERS}
        ${AVFORMAT_LDFLAGS_OTHERS}
        ${AVFILTER_LDFLAGS_OTHERS}
        ${AVDEVICE_LDFLAGS_OTHERS}
        ${AVUTIL_LDFLAGS_OTHERS}
        ${SWRESAMPLE_LDFLAGS_OTHERS}
        ${SWSCALE_LDFLAGS_OTHERS}
        )
```

Comment: You forgot to show **your code** (`CMakeLists.txt`) which declares executable and performs linking.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thank you. I edited the question to include cmakelists, to take advantage of code formatting.

Comment: If you link with IMPORTED target `PkgConfig::AVCODEC`, then there is no needs to use `AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIRS` or `AVCODEC_LDFLAGS` - they are already contained in that IMPORTED target. Would you not use IMPORTED target, you should use `AVCODEC_LDFLAGS_OTHERS` variable instead of `AVCODEC_LDFLAGS` one: The latter includes libraries (`AVCODEC_LINK_LIBRARIES`), which are properly processed with `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thank you for your suggestion. I took out repetitive declarations from my cmakelists, and wondering if there's anything else you'd recommend to address the issue?   I have updated my build_output, and updated the CMakelists file for your review.  Would displaying my 'env' here help in any way to research the issue?  Also, my code at this point is incredibly simple, I could also add it to the body of my question, if needed.